# Benchmarking DNS queries

Tags: networking, software-recommendation, dns, benchmarks

I've recently switched to a router that allows me to set the network's DNS resolution to an internal server. Because of that, I'm playing around with a few DNS caching techniques (like bind9, pdnsd, etc) to speed DNS resolution up.

The problem is I don't have a good way to benchmark queries. I'm ideally looking for:

- Something that can test a whole load of real domains.
  The number of distinct tests is what is most important here.
- Some sort of way of comparing tests against each other. Benchmarks need metrics. A time to resolution seems logical but I'm open to suggestions.
- Something that is automated and uninvolved. I'm happy to script something but it needs to churn through everything  and arrive at a single result without further processing so I can decide if the current DNS caching implementation is working.

This is as much as a "what's a good way to benchmark DNS" as it is "are there any tools to benchmark DNS". If there's something that does all this for me already, that's a great answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe *namebench* does what you need. It is available in the repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install namebench
```

Read more: https://code.google.com/p/namebench/